# Scipy solve_bvp() changes array size during iteration

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a 4th order ODE of a beam on an elastic foundation. I am applying this problem to a laterally-loaded pile that is embedded in several soil layers which can be specified in the code. An array `c` holds the system's stiffness parameters which I need to multiply elementwise with `y[0]`.

[image]

However, a problem appears as at some point in the source code `y[0]` gets shorter by 1 element, and I get the error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40,) (39,)
```

Does anyone know how to fix that? I have tried adding

```
if c.size < y[0].size:
        np.delete(c,-1)
```

right before the return statement in `fun(x,y)` but without success.

```
# ODE-Solver ---------------------------------------------------

from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np


#Input ---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*

layers = [2,2,6] #m
M_Es = (10**3)*[45,20,60] #MN/m2

E_c = 33.6*10**6

F = 1000 #kN
D = 1 #m
nodes = 40

#---------------------------------------------------

#total length of the pile:
L = sum(layers) #m

#x-coordinates of the pile
x = np.linspace(0,L,nodes)

#Empty arr. for soil's compression modulus:
M_E = np.zeros(nodes)

#soil layer boundaries' depths:
depth = np.zeros(len(layers)+1)

for i in range(1,len(depth)):
    depth[i] = sum(layers[:i])


i=0

#assign M_E to the nodes of the current soil layer "j"
#while x lies between two boundaries assign the i-th value in "M_Es" array
for j in range(len(depth)-1):
    while x[i] >= sum_layers[j] and x[i] < sum_layers[j+1]:
        M_E[i] = M_Es[j]
        i += 1
    
#calculate the spring stiffness of the soil "k_sh" and the flexural rigidity of the pile "EI"
k_sh = 1.4*M_E/D #kN/m3
EI = E_c*0.25*np.pi*(D*0.5)**4 #kNm2


c = k_sh*D/(EI)

def fun(x, y):
    return np.vstack((y[1],y[2],y[3],np.multiply(-c,y[0])))

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[2], yb[2], ya[3]+F/EI, yb[3]])

y_a = np.zeros((4, x.size))

res_a = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_a)
```

Comment: The code is, unfortunately, not stand alone. Can you modify please. A little explanation of what you are trying to do, would also be nice. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added more comments in the code and a picture of the static system I am trying to model. The main point here is that I want to multiply `c` and `y[0]`, but at some point when `fun(x,y)` is called and used, `y[0]` loses one of its entries and is therefore 1 element shorter than `c`. This is why we get this error, but after having looked at the source code of `solve_bvp()` I could not figure out why.

Comment: While you provide the initial grid, you can make no assumptions on the changes that the solver makes to the grid, refining it in places, and, as it seems, thinning out nodes in other places. Use interpolation to get the correct array of values `c(x)` to be used.

Comment: Could you suggest a way to implement that? @Lutz Lehman

Comment: @Lutz Lehman I mean `x` just remains the same, it is `y[0]` that gets modified somewhere inside the `solve_bvp()`. How should I go about interpolating, if I don't have the new set of x-values that the modified `y[0]` is using?

Comment: What has `x` to do with this error? The complaint is about the multiplication `c*y[0]` where `y[0]` only has 39 entries. But that does not matter. You just can not assume what `x` is in the call to `fun`. The solver expects that you return the derivative lists to the given points, that is a result that is equal to `np.transpose([ fun(x[k],y[:,k]) for k in range(len(x)) ])`. Again, independent of what `x` is, may it contain 1, 2 or 40 elements.

Comment: Yes, but you have suggested interpolating to get `c(x)`. If I want to do that I need the new x-values for `c(x)`, otherwise I cannot interpolate. Or did you mean something different?